# How to use react components inside a Gatsby plugin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I want to create a Gatsby plugin with an index.js file but I want to render React components inside the plugin. I imported react:

```js
const React = require('react');
const MyComponent = require('myComponent');
modules.exports = () => {
    const myRenderedComponent = React.render(MyComponent);
    ...
}
```

But it fails because it doesn't understand the `import` statement I have in `myComponent.js`.
How can I render a component inside a Gatsby plugin instead of having to write the HTML?

I would be too silly to write the component's HTML by hand instead of just using the component itself

Comment: All your `import`s in your component can be changed to `require` and that will make it be compatible (and will continue to work in the same way). I am not sure if your component will work inside your plugin though, but at least you can try.

Comment: @Mindastic Now it says unexpected token '<' maybe JSX isn't supported?